# Initializing D3D9 causes a 3rd-party library to stop working

Tags: c++, dll, wxwidgets, xul, direct3d

First, the general situation... a 3rd-party library loaded through a DLL does rendering into a HWND. It's simple 2D rendering and is not directly using D3D in a way I can see - a dependency walk on the DLL shows lots of D3DKMT functions like `D3DKMTCreateDevice` but not regular D3D calls like `IDirect3D9::CreateDevice`.
When I call `IDirect3D9::CreateDevice`, the 3rd-party rendering goes screwy. It doesn't complain, but simply renders everything as black rectangles. My own rendering works fine.

The specifics... the 3rd-party DLL is Mozilla XULRunner 1.9.x, which is the core of FireFox (not 2.0 which features hardware acceleration), wrapped in the wxWidgets wxWebConnect library. wxWC loads the XUL DLL and provides a web-browser GUI component.

I have a working app using wx & wxWebConnect here, a compiled EXE and the code:
http://www.kirix.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=911#p2605

Here is my real-life code, it's slightly bound to wxWidgets but not enough to make it hard to read - I get a HWND from a random window simply to initialize D3D but never render to it:

```
void MyFrame::OnD3DButton( wxCommandEvent &event )
{
    static bool initialized = false;
    static LPDIRECT3D9 mpD3D = NULL;
    static LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 mpD3DDevice=NULL;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        wxButton *button=wxDynamicCast(event.GetEventObject(), wxButton);
        HWND mHWnd = (HWND)button->GetHandle();
        mpD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS md3dpp;
        ZeroMemory( &md3dpp, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS) );
        md3dpp.Windowed                 = true;
        md3dpp.SwapEffect               = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        // triple buffer if VSync is on
        md3dpp.BackBufferCount          = 1;
        md3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil   = 0;
        md3dpp.hDeviceWindow            = mHWnd;
        md3dpp.BackBufferWidth          = 0;
        md3dpp.BackBufferHeight         = 0;
        md3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0;
        md3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
        md3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
        md3dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
        md3dpp.MultiSampleQuality = 0;

        HRESULT hr = mpD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,mHWnd,
            D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED|D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING,&md3dpp,&mpD3DDevice);
        if(FAILED(hr))
            wxMessageBox(wxString("mpD3D->CreateDevice() FAILED"));
        else
        {
            wxMessageBox(wxString("mpD3D->CreateDevice() SUCCEEDED"));
            initialized = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be that CreateDevice will modify the FPU state unless you pass the flag `D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE`. It took me a really long time to find this when it bit me.

Comment: This is most probably the problem.  Its a pain of an issue that.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I only tried this just to cross it off the list and IT WORKED! I have no clue why on earth it would screw up a web-rendering engine but there you go. Now what do I _do_ with this information?

Comment: The reason is that it will screw up anything that uses floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

do you create the D3D Device with the same hwnd like the one the 3rd-party dll uses?

in this case maybe the 3rd-party software is still drawing it's stuff, but direct3d just renders on top of it, so you only see the d3d output.

Comment: No, a separate one. Also, I am not doing _any_ rendering. All I call is `Direct3DCreate9` and `CreateDevice`, that's it.

Comment: how do you create the device? could you post the parameters? do you have debug on? maybe there's something in the log that indicates trouble on createdevice

Comment: Are you using WindowsXP, Vista or 7?? Are you creating a D3D9 device or a D3D9EX device??

Comment: I put an example together for the wxWebConnect forum, it includes my D3D code. See download attached here: http://www.kirix.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=911#p2605

Comment: try setting BackBuffer Width and height to some specific size, and setting not setting stuff like screenrefreshrate or multisamplequality if you only set it 0. maybe also try changing to create the device with D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING. as you say all goes messy only on creating the d3d device, i guess the settings somehow don't go together well with one another, or mess the 3rdparty stuff although i have difficulties understanding why this could be

Comment: That's just one example of minimal D3D init. Looking for problems in those combination of flags isn't the answer because it breaks also in 3rd-party libraries which do their own D3D setup more properly. The conflicting library doesn't use D3D that I can see anyway, hence the confusion.

Comment: did you try different drivers?

Comment: Tried multiple PCs. People on the Kirix forum can reproduce also.

Comment: isn't there any directx or xulrunner debug log? showing some kind of errors/warnings?